# How to optimize LIKE queries with indexes in CnosDB?

Tags: cnosdb

I have a table called products in CnosDB containing a substantial amount of data. There's a column named product_name, and I want to perform a fuzzy search with a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE 'search_term%';
```

Due to the large volume of data in the table, this query becomes quite slow. I have already attempted to create an index on the product_name column, but it doesn't seem to improve the query performance significantly.

Could you please advise on how to utilize indexes effectively in CnosDB to optimize LIKE queries for fuzzy searches? Are there any other optimization techniques to enhance the execution speed of such queries?

Thank you for your assistance!